# Accounts-ui with amazon Web Services and apk android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, meteor

Why my meteor app works fine with appname-meteor.com like server, specifically in accounts-ui. 
`meteor build ~/appname --server=appname.meteor.com`

and install the signed apk,the login link seen in my android device.
[image]

But when I do this (server ip is from aws):

`meteor build ~/appname --server=0.0.0.0`
in the signed apk not seen the login link...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved! 
`meteor build ~/appname --server=ec2-0-0-0-0.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`